# CATextLayer's `foregroundColor` not working with CAKeyframeAnimation and timeOffset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cakeyframeanimation, catextlayer

I need to animate the color of `CATextLayer`, and the animation itself works:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"foregroundColor"];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.values = @[(id)([UIColor redColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor blueColor].CGColor)];
[textLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```

However if I want to control the progress of animation by setting the layer's speed to 0, it doesn't work:

```
animation.speed = 0;
...
textLayer.timeOffset = 0.5f;
```

Is there anything I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this property may only animatable for macOS 10.6 and later.As the  [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/catextlayer/1515305-foregroundcolor) said.

Comment: @Guan Thanks! I saw that but mis-understood it, I thought the limitation is on macOS but not on iOS, now I read it again and got it.

Comment: @Guan The docs say "Implicit animation"... So does this mean that other platforms require 'Explicit animation', or won't work at all?